# python pandas dataframe : removing selected rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, something like :

```
df = pd.read_csv('fruit.csv')

print(df)

   fruitname  quant
0      apple     10
1      apple     11
2      apple     13
3     banana     10
4     banana     20
5     banana     30
6     banana     40
7       pear     10
8       pear    102
9       pear   1033
10      pear   1012
11      pear    101
12      pear    100
13      pear   1044
14    orange     10
```

I want to remove the last entry, PER FRUIT, if that fruit has an odd (uneven) number of entries (%2 == 1). Without looping through the dataframe. So the end result of the above would be:

-- remove the last apple, since apple occurs 3 times
-- remove the last pear
-- remove the last (only) orange

resulting in:

```
   fruitname  quant
0      apple     10
1      apple     11
2     banana     10
3     banana     20
4     banana     30
5     banana     40
6       pear     10
7       pear    102
8       pear   1033
9       pear   1012
10      pear    101
11      pear    100
```

Is this possible? Or do I have to loop through the DF? I've been googling for 4 days, and just can't figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the apply function:

```
def remove_last_odd_row(fr):
    nrow = fr.shape[0]
    if nrow % 2 > 0:
        return fr[:(nrow - 1)]
    else:
        return fr

fr = fr.groupby("fruitname").apply(remove_last_odd_row).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 6):

Determine the number of items per fruit using [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts) and build a list of them based on whether there are an odd number. 
We can achieve this by just using `%` modulus operator to generate either a `1` or `0`, cast this using [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html#pandas.Series.astype) to create a boolean mask.

Use the boolean mask to mask the index of `value_counts`.

Now you have a list of fruit, iterate over each fruit by filtering the df and get the last index label using [`iloc[-1]`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position) and `.name` attribute and append this to a list.

Now [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop) these labels in the list:

```
In [393]:
fruits = df['fruitname'].value_counts().index[(df['fruitname'].value_counts() % 2).astype(bool)]
idx = []
for fruit in fruits:
    idx.append(df[df['fruitname']==fruit].iloc[-1].name)
df.drop(idx)

Out[393]:
   fruitname  quant
0      apple     10
1      apple     11
3     banana     10
4     banana     20
5     banana     30
6     banana     40
7       pear     10
8       pear    102
9       pear   1033
10      pear   1012
11      pear    101
12      pear    100
```

Breaking the above down:

```
In [394]:
df['fruitname'].value_counts()

Out[394]:
pear      7
banana    4
apple     3
orange    1
Name: fruitname, dtype: int64

In [398]:   
df['fruitname'].value_counts() % 2

Out[398]:
pear      1
banana    0
apple     1
orange    1
Name: fruitname, dtype: int64

In [399]:
fruits = df['fruitname'].value_counts().index[(df['fruitname'].value_counts() % 2).astype(bool)]
fruits

Out[399]:
Index(['pear', 'apple', 'orange'], dtype='object')

In [401]:    
for fruit in fruits:
    print(df[df['fruitname']==fruit].iloc[-1].name)

13
2
14
```

Actually you can use [`last_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index) instead of `iloc[-1].name` so the following would work:

```
fruits = df['fruitname'].value_counts().index[(df['fruitname'].value_counts() % 2).astype(bool)]
idx = []
for fruit in fruits:
    idx.append(df[df['fruitname']==fruit].last_valid_index())
df.drop(idx)
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative approach to EdChum's, which uses `groupby`:

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby("fruitname")["fruitname"]
>>> lengths = grouped.transform(len)
>>> df.loc[~((lengths % 2 == 1) & (grouped.cumcount() == lengths-1))]
   fruitname  quant
0      apple     10
1      apple     11
3     banana     10
4     banana     20
5     banana     30
6     banana     40
7       pear     10
8       pear    102
9       pear   1033
10      pear   1012
11      pear    101
12      pear    100
```

---

This works by using `transform` (and `cumcount`, which kind of behaves like a type of transform because it broadcasts up to the original index) to give us a frame-length series we can work with:

```
>>> lengths
0     3
1     3
2     3
3     4
4     4
5     4
6     4
7     7
8     7
9     7
10    7
11    7
12    7
13    7
14    1
Name: fruitname, dtype: object
>>> grouped.cumcount()
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     0
4     1
5     2
6     3
7     0
8     1
9     2
10    3
11    4
12    5
13    6
14    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with pandas but here is an answer.

```
for fruit in pd.unique(df.fruitname):
    df1=df[df.fruitname==fruit]
    if len(df1)%2 == 1:
        df=df.drop(df1.last_valid_index())
```